# Set ASP Session From PHP

Tags: php, session, asp-classic

Lets say I have a session called "access" that is checked for with ASP and has it's own login system.

Is it possible for me to use a PHP script to see that "access" session so it is automatically set?

If this isn't possible does anyone know how I can get the ASP equivalent to:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST['xxxxx'] == "yyyyy"){
        $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
        header('Location: admin/manage_admin.php');
    }

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: login.php?logout');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do something similar in asp would be

```
<%
If Request.Form("xxxxx") = "yyyyy" then
Session("id") = 1
Response.Redirect("admin/manage_admin.asp")
End If

If Request.Querystring("logout") = 1 then
Session.Abandon
Response.Redirect("login.asp")
End If
%>
```

Sharing session variables between different technologies is difficult.  What you would probably need to look at is a way of storing them in a database.  There's a MSDN article which discusses how to do this with Classic ASP and ASP.net, which might help you understand the concept.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

The usual hack to get around this though is for a page in one language to pass variables to a page in another via either an ajax call or an invisible iFrame